# My VS Code is unable to display sout as System.out.println for new java files that I make

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I close VS code and open again then in the previous made files `sout` as `System.out.println` is visible. I dont know what is happening.

Some dailog box related to usage of RedHat or something had come. I didnt know what it is and pressed cancel from then this problem is happening.

I will be really thankful if someone helps me out. Thanks

Comment: what does `sout as System.out.println` mean?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans on VS code if we write sout or sysout.. The whole function System.out.println gets displayed which we can enter directly.. but for me its not showing now for the new java files that I am making

Comment: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191

Comment: @starball is this problem being faced by many people?

Comment: judging by the (currently 6) questions that have been posted, and multiple issue tickets, yes- this is a problem being faced by multiple people. sit tight and stay tuned for updates.

Answer (score -1):

Judging from the latest reply:

> this issue has been fixed in the latest vscode@1.80.1 version.

*https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191#issuecomment-1635181642*

Comment: please don't answer duplicate questions. vote to close as a duplicate